# Encrypt disks using SED and store keys in TPM?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, nvme, tpm

I'm buying servers lately and all of them have disks that support TCG Opal full-disk encryption (aka SED).  What I'd like to do is:

- Store data encrypted-at-rest on the disks (NVMe & SAS).
- Not be required to enter a password/passphrase at server boot.
- Have encryption keys be stored in the server's TPM 2.0 module.

To simplify, the goal is to "lock" the data to the server, ensuring that if a disk is removed and inserted in another machine the data is inaccessible.  I've seen [sedutil](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Encrypting-your-drive) but haven't yet played with it as it looks like it requires entering a passphrase at every boot.  I have hundreds of servers I'd like to enable this on, so having to enter a passphrase (is it per-disk?) at reboot is not an option.  TPM seems like a natural place to store this kind of thing, so I'm wondering if anyone's done anything like this. The only reference I can find to anything like this is in [this Micron white paper](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/white-paper/self_encrypting_drives_white_paper.pdf).  The servers are all running Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).  There's more than one disk per server, if that matters.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I find myself in a similar situation now.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Ended up using LUKS at the filesystem level and just eating the performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I appreciate it. SED seems like such a great idea in theory, but the practical tools for interacting with it leave a lot to be desired in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

A few years too late, but depending on your server configuration, a Broadcom RAID controller with SafeStore, such as 9540-8i or 9560-8i, should be a solution for you.  Instead of storing the keys in the TPM, it provides its own security module.  But your requirements of password-less startup and unreadable disk if a disk is removed should be satisfied.

Note: if the attacker also removes the controller card, it may be possible to access the data.  I have not verified this.